# spring json returning empty arrays when the value is null

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

in spring application im currently processing a json string and returning that in my response

```
public class MyResponse {
    private String name;

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // other properties, getters, and setters
}
```

when items is not set, id expect the response json to contain []... but instead the property is excluded. How can i add this property always to the json response?
When it has data send the array as usual, when it doesnt output []

Comment: can u show more code on serialization part or controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very incomplete since you have not mentioned what library are you using for Json serialization/deserialization etc.

I will provide a sample code that uses ObjectMapper from Jackson library which satisfies your requirement

**MyResponse.class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyResponse {

    private String name;

    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // other properties, getters, and setters


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyResponse{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", items=" + items +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**TestClient.class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonStr = "{\"name\":\"Xyz\",\"items\":[]}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyResponse myResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr,MyResponse.class);
        System.out.println(myResponse);
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myResponse));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
MyResponse{name='Stacy', items=[]}

{"name":"Stacy","items":[]}
```

I hope this will help you.
If Not,Please add more details in the question so that the community can help you out.